# Why is my winform window infront of other windows, even when using HWND_BOTTOM?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My code is

```
    private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const UInt32 BOTTOM_FLAGS = SWP_NOSIZE;
```

...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, BOTTOM_FLAGS);
    }
```

It should be behind all other windows, as said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

However, it goes infront of all other windows and the other windows need to be clicked to go infront.

Comment: Does your application have other windows? or you expecting the application to access the Z-stack of all applications?

I would test if the SetWindowsPos returns a value, that should indicate if it's working as expected.

Comment: This is the only app window, I'm  expecting the application to access the Z-stack of all applications. When I switch from HWND_BOTTOM to HWND_TOPMOST and from IntPtr(1); to IntPtr(-1);, it stays and won't move from top, unlike this where it goes on top but it can be taken off top if I press something in the task bar.

Comment: `SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);` -- In `Form.Load`? What happens after that? -- Make sure yours is the only app that tries this :)

Comment: It has the same behaviour as before. It's infront of everything until I click something else.

Comment: Can you show what you actually changed in your call to `SetWindowPos()`? Or did you set as before `BOTTOM_FLAGS = SWP_NOSIZE`, which of course does nothing (except ignoring the `0, 0` size specified)?

Comment: In Form1_Load 
` SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);`

Comment: at top of class:
`   private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    private const UInt32 SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
    private const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    private const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const UInt32 BOTTOM_FLAGS = SWP_NOSIZE;

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);'

Comment: Not good in `Form.Load`, move it to the `Form.Shown` event (better, override `OnShown()`,  calling the function after `base.OnShown(e))` or override `WndProc` <- if you want to keep your Form at the bottom of the z-order. -- As a note, `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` is not required, `BOOL` is managed, `BOOLEAN` is not.

Comment: I'm getting the error 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Error creating window handle.'' upon program.cs running 'Application.Run(new Form1());'.  My code i added is

Comment: `
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
`

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what I was missing, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I was missing 'base.WndProc(ref m);' at the end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding more flags and moving some of my code to WndProc, as can be seen in the comments.

Comment: Also, not just override WndProc and call `SetWindowPos()` no matter what message is received. You're going to call that function a hundred thousands times per minute. Maybe just trap `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` (you should also check the value of the `hwndInsertAfter` member of the `WINDOWPOS` struct that LParam points to; way less important though)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).